# navigate from one page to another in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I navigate from one page to another page in xcode? remember without using the interface builder... I want the answer programmatically?

Comment: the more question marks you put after each sentence the less your chances to get an answer. really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is not much clear but still I would like to give a try...

You can use

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"<name of xib>" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
[yourViewController release];
```

In case the new view is also to be created programmatically, you can do that in the viewDidLoad method of YourViewControllerClass and change the initialization to

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewControllerClass alloc] init];
```

In YourViewController when you wish to come back to previous view on some button action you can use

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Another way that you can do is

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewControllerClass alloc] init];
[self addSubview:[yourViewController view]];
```

and to remove the view you can use

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope this works for you, if yes please communicate....:)

Answer (score 3):

Pls be more precise if you want to get what you want.

If you are using view controllers within navigationcontroller you can make use of its `pushViewController:` or `presentModalViewController:`. Or if you just want to show another view you can just add the next view to existing view as subview.

Comment: i am new to the iphone application development. i have one button in my application. if i pressed that button i want to go to the next page. i dont want to use the interface builder for this. i have to do it programatically. if you have the time means please give the coding for that... thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller in your app?

Comment: ya i have navigavion conroller in my app

Comment: Create the viewcontroller which is to be pushed on to the navigation stack. I mean create the view controller which will control the actions for the next view. Then push that viewController's instance through the method i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

//Appdelegate.m

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

//In viewcontroller1.M
- (IBAction)GoToNext:(id)sender 
{
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```